# Boot-Repair Error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Hi I have a boot report [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6476851/). I need to know what settings to turn on. Default repair does not work, there is a /boot partition under sda7, but turning on that setting alone, makes it so the grub shell comes up. I need the boot menu. I have a tri-boot laptop, Opensuse, Win7, and Fedora 19.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see Ubuntu anywhere? This is a site on Ubuntu issues. They may shut this thread down.

You have grub legacy (??) in the MBR. You need grub2 for whichever install you want to boot primarily in the MBR. Unselect auto repair in Boot-Repair and select update MBR and choose which install to install to sda's MBR.

You also show a grub2 in the extended partition  (PBR) with the boot flag. You may have been able to boot to the grub2 install in a PBR with a Windows boot loader. But grub does not use boot flag. Windows does need a boot flag to directly boot from MBR or make repairs to a partition. Do not think Windows 7 will boot from sda1 which is now FAT16? Not sure how you changed that as Windows 7 boot files are normally in a NTFS partition. But you also show boot files in sda2 so that should work if BCD is correct.

You will need to add lvm2 drivers and mount the Fedora install to get grub2's os-prober to find the Fedora install. Or manually copy boot files into 40_custom. Best to install Fedora directly into an ext4 partition when multi-booting as the advantage of LVM of resizing partitions works better when the LVM is an entire drive.